# writing large int to disk with c++

Tags: c++, io, gmp

I have a lot of 20 byte integers I want to write to disk.  I have them stored in ram using the GMP `mpz_class`

I have tried using the following test code but in the file is 20x 0s not the expected `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 21F882C7`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    mpz_class userId;
    userId="569934535";

    //open user file
    string fileName= "test.bin";
    ofstream mapFile(fileName,ios::binary);

    //save userId
    mpz_class temp=userId;  //copy so original not destroyed(never reused in example but in real life it would)
    unsigned int bytes[20];
    for (unsigned char i=0;i<20;i++) {
        mpz_class t=temp%256;
        bytes[19-i]=t.get_ui();
        temp/=256;
    }
    mapFile.write((char*)&bytes,20);//expecting to write 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 21F882C7
    mapFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I am new to c++ what am I missing?  also any suggestions if there is a better way to do this?

**Edit 1:**

Thanks for comments for pointing out that I was using an int where I should have been using a char.  But even better @kelalaka pointed out mpz_class had a built in function which got me to 2 different options

The below is a drop in replacement for `mpz_out_raw` excepts it takes a `mpz_class` as input instead of `mpz_t op`  It saves 3 bytes per number written assuming you are always using less then 256 bytes but it is 5x slower.

```
void nonStandard(FILE *stream, mpz_class op) {
    unsigned char length=0;
    unsigned char bytes[127];
    while (op>0) {
        mpz_class t=op%256;
        bytes[length+1]=t.get_ui();
        op/=256;
        length++;
    }
    unsigned char buffer[length+1];
    buffer[0]=length;
    for (char i=length-1;i>=0;i--) buffer[length-i]=bytes[i];
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char),length+1, stream);
}
```

Comment: `unsigned int bytes[20];` -> `unsigned char bytes[20];`

Comment: ^^ Because int is usually 4 bytes and char is 1, so `unsigned int bytes[20];` would give you 4 * 20 bytes.

Comment: thanks yes.  had that way originally but the ```temp%256``` is not castable to unsigned char.  never corrected when i figured out needed to use ```t.get_ui()```.

Comment: There is already raw input/output in the library... [5.12 Input and Output Functions](https://gmplib.org/manual/I_002fO-of-Integers)

Comment: thanks for pointing out.  inefficient space wise since I will never have more then 255 byte number but more worrying then wasting 3 bytes for every number I need to write down is the note that it is not compatible with an older version of gmp which makes me wonder if it may become not compatible some day in the future.

Comment: @kelalaka well I did some tests.  Doing 1 million writes using ```mpz_out_raw``` took 330ms using my own slightly more space efficient version took 1710ms.  So ```mpz_out_raw``` was 5x faster and both produce identical results except for the 3 extra 0 bytes.

Comment: +1, @MatthewCornelisse if you turn your edit with performance tests ( shot and long data, number of iterations etc), it will be a good answer. Note that your comment and edits are conflicting about the speed of `mpz_out_raw` ( well at least for me as it was written)

Comment: as you wish.  think the reading different is in in edit I say that my function is 5x slower where as comment I say mpz_out_raw was 5x faster.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out gmp has a function for writing the number to a file streem `mpz_out_raw` however it uses a 4 byte length value which for my use is over kill so I wrote a similar function that only used a 1 byte length value.  Though my function saves 3 bytes of storage data it takes 5 times longer to run then the native function so is probably not desired.

Below is my function `nonStandard` and an example script to test its speed.  It will write 1000000 numbers to the disk and time how long it took.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;

#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
using std::chrono::time_point;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::milliseconds;
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;


/**
 * This function only works with numbers up to 2^1016
 * @param stream
 * @param op
 */
void nonStandard(FILE *stream, mpz_class op) {
    unsigned char length=0;
    unsigned char bytes[127];
    while (op>0) {
        mpz_class t=op%256;
        bytes[length]=t.get_ui();
        op/=256;
        length++;
    }
    unsigned char buffer[length+1];
    buffer[0]=length;
    for (char i=length-1;i>=0;i--) buffer[length-i]=bytes[i]; // NOLINT(cppcoreguidelines-narrowing-conversions)
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char),length+1, stream);
}

int main() {
    mpz_class userId;
    userId="345474756569934535";
    FILE* mapFile = fopen("mpz_out_raw.bin", "wb");



    time_point<Clock> start = Clock::now();
    //test start
    for (int i=0;i<1000000;i++) {
        userId+=7;
        mpz_out_raw(mapFile,userId.get_mpz_t());
    }
    fclose(mapFile);
    //test end
    time_point<Clock> end = Clock::now();
    milliseconds diff = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start);
    std::cout << "mpz_out_raw: " << diff.count() << "ms" << std::endl;



    userId="345474756569934535";
    mapFile = fopen("nonStandard.bin", "wb");
    start = Clock::now();
    //test start
    for (int i=0;i<1000000;i++) {
        userId+=7;
        nonStandard(mapFile,userId);
    }
    fclose(mapFile);
    //test end
    end = Clock::now();
    diff = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start);
    std::cout << "nonStandard: " << diff.count() << "ms" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is better to include the output of the run and compiled CPU etc. similar to I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65833999/1820553) and you can remove the edit from your question...

Comment: I thought about that but thought maybe people should just try on there system and see what is better storage space or conversion speed.

Comment: Then again could be interesting to run on a few machines and see.

Comment: Nowadays, memory is cheap and time is invaluable. If you store 20-byte integers with 4-byte length overhead, this is just 14% more space than storing them with 1-byte length overhead. In a 1TB disk this means you can store 45.8 billion 20-byte integers with 4-byte overhead instead of 54.2 billion 20-byte integers with 1-byte overhead, which means like loosing $10 of a 1TB $70 SSD disk. Do you need that much numbers? Also note that when you block read data from disk, your numbers will not be memory-aligned, so you will need an additional copy to handle them.

Comment: Also your `nonStandard` function is highly `nonPortable` and `nonEfficient`. For write efficiency you might want to write all data (or a significant chunk of it) to a temporary memory buffer first, and then just use one `fwrite` instruction (just as `mpz\out_raw.c` does).

Comment: why is it not portable?  It always writes it in bigendian.  as long as your code also reads that way it should be fine(unless I am missing something).  the memory buffer is what I was missing though to do this efficiently.

Comment: Portability concerns several factors, of which GMP usually takes care very well, byte order and word size being the most important ones but not the only ones. A limb in GMP can be 32 or 64 bits in size according to platform, and all GMP functions always take good care of that. Also, `inp_raw.c` and `out_raw.c` read and write from and to host order and network order, according to platform. Your code does write to network order (bigendian), but reading will be a little more trick. But some other details are hideous, see, for example, see the Cray preprocessor directive on `out_raw.c`.

Comment: Also, your code is very inefficient, as it uses `%256` to extract bytes from `mpz` data. In contrast, GMP raw functions directly access the `mpz_t` struct fields (`_mp_size`, of which the absolute value gives you the actual number of limbs in use of that `mpz_t`, and `_mp_d` which is a pointer to where the actual numerical juice is stored in memory), and - according to build system endianness preprocessor defined symbols - use very efficient swap functions to handle host to network order. Lots of issues people from GMP already encountered and handled on their way here.

Comment: Not to mention the handling of the 'nails' experimental feature of which all of the GMP code is well prepared to deal with (but chances are you are not using that feature). In general, I would say use directly the GMP raw read and write functions, but you could want to change them to be more efficient so they read/write not only a single `mpz`, but a large number of your 20-byte variables, for example, by passing a `mpz` array to them, storing on a large buffer, and them writing to disk.

Comment: Yes my testing the efficiency of my code convinced me to use the built in raw.  Though your comments above make me worry raw may not be portable.  My test code always reads and writes big endian even though my machine is little endian.  That way any machine it runs on generates files identical.  You make it sound like raw is machine specific though my tests show it seems to write big endian only

Comment: What I meant is: GMP `raw` functions are fully portable, since they identify host endianness at compile time, and always write to disk in network byte order (bigendian), so using `raw` you should not worry at all, even if you write to disk in a bigendian machine and read from disk in a little endian machine, or vice-versa.

Comment: thanks.  Was pretty sure that was what it was doing.  For the record I am using raw.  my above code is way to slow.

Comment: Your instinct to do it yourself is all the way right, as it enlightens your mind with possible ways of doing stuff, and never accept - at first - things as they are! But when I look into GMP's code, I feel these guys have my hands down competely, and that's nice to know so much has been done which satisfies me far beyond my wildest expectations.